# How to Add these type of nicely highlighted code examples to my WordPress blog That can be copy pasted by the reader?

Tags: php, wordpress

[Code blocklike in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGpO2.jpg)
I want to add example codes nicely on my WordPress blog. So that the reader can try them by copy-pasting.Is there a plugin to do that. Or can I type it somewhere and copy paste it into my blog via a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are prefer to go with a plugin then try [Syntax Highlighter Evolved](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). This will easily display code on your WordPress site.

By default, WordPress filters out any raw code added into blog posts, pages, widgets, or comments.

The plugin will support most of the languages as mentioned in [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like Geshi plugin, maybe its prism...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-geshi-highlight/

So yes, there are Plugins for that. Although I'd prefer Prism. https://wordpress.org/plugins/ank-prism-for-wp/

There are tons of plugins, just try some and choose the one that fits your needs the best.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/syntax+highlight/